# R date sequence - first n days from each month

Tags: r

I want to generate a date sequence. I can do it with

```
seq(from=as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 0:00", tz="UTC"),
    to=as.POSIXct("2012-12-19 23:00", tz="UTC"),
    by="hour")
```

Now I want a sequence containing only the first `n` days from each month. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
n <- 1:10
indx <- as.numeric(format(dt, "%d")) %in% n
dtSub <- dt[indx]
```

You can make this into a function

```
f1 <- function(x, n){
n1 <- seq(n)
indx <- as.numeric(format(x, "%d")) %in% n1
x[indx]
}

res <- f1(dt, 10)
max(as.numeric(format(res, "%d")))
#[1] 10
```

#### data

```
dt <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 0:00", tz="UTC"),
to=as.POSIXct("2012-12-19 23:00", tz="UTC"),
by="hour")
```